# Transforming command line SQL to POST method SpringBoot

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot

How can I transform that command line to PostMapping method in Spring?
Considering 2 Entitys, Entity **Equipment**(UUID id, UUID equipment_model_id, String name)and another Entity **Equipment_model**(UUID id,String name).

**Equipment_model** have an **Primary key**.

**Equipment** have a **foreign key** relational to primary key Equipment_model

Consider UUID from Equipment_model = a3540227-2f0e-4362-9517-92f41dabbfdf

*If i write at command line:*

`INSERT INTO operation.equipment(id, equipment_model_id,name) VALUES(gen_random_uuid(), 'a3540227-2f0e-4362-9517-92f41dabbfdf','test')`

**RESULT**: `Query returned successfully`

Howhever i'm trying some days in POST method and having same error:
**"message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [equipment_model_id" of relation "equipment]",**

**public class Equipment implements Serializable {**
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID equipment_model_id;
    private String name;

//Getters and Setters
```

**public interface EquipmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Equipment,UUID>{**

```
}
```

**public class EquipmentResource {**

```
@Autowired
EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository;

@GetMapping("/equipments")
public List<Equipment> listEquipments(){
    return equipmentRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping("/equipmentp")
public Equipment salvaProduto(@RequestBody  Equipment equipment) {
    return equipmentRepository.save(equipment);
}
```

}

EQUIPMENT_MODEL:

**public class Equipment_model implements Serializable{**

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private UUID id;
private String name;
//GETTErs Setters }
```

**public interface Equipment_modelRepository  extends JpaRepository<Equipment_model,UUID>{**

```
}
```

**public class Equipment_modelResource {**

```
@Autowired
private Equipment_modelRepository equipment_modelRepository;

@GetMapping("/equipment_model")
@Operation(summary = "Create a clone", description = "Create a clone with the information of the body.")    
public List<Equipment_model> listModel(){
    return equipment_modelRepository.findAll();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are trying to generate the equipment model in your equipment instead of relating one thing to another.
Instead of defining:

```java
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID equipment_model_id;
```

you should try to reference it to:

```java
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="equipment_model_id")
    private Equipment_model equipment_model;
```

This way, it will not try to generate a new ID that does not have a corresponding value.